# Meaning of disposition

Tags: meaning

Is it correct to say "My disposition and dedication have become more rooted in this field"? What does disposition mean here?

I looked it up in a dictionary, but still can't completely feel the meaning or understand it. Does disposition there mean interest, tendency, passion, etc?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you looked the word up in a dictionary? If not please do. If you have please explain what you don't understand about it (either in general or specifically in that sentence).

Comment: Thanks, Avon. I did look it up in a dictionary, but still can't completely feel the meaning or understand it. Does disposition there mean interest, tendency, passion, etc? Thanks.

Comment: Disposition has several meanings.  You want the one that refers to one's personality and "mood" -- cheerful, somber, unemotional, friendly, distant, argumentative, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It has two possible meanings (at least [according to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=disposition)):

> 1. a person's inherent qualities of mind and character.
>      *"a sweet-natured girl of a placid disposition"*
>      *"the book is not recommended to readers of a nervous disposition"*
>     synonyms: temperament, nature, character,
>      constitution, make-up, grain, humour, temper, mentality, turn of
>      mind;
> 2. the way in which something is placed or arranged, especially in relation to other things.
>      *"the plan shows the disposition of the rooms"*

The latter could work as a metaphor: the orientation of his rooting in the field. It would be a bit of a pun too - alluding to 'field' in the more common sense of the word. (Root is a bit of a pun there after all.)

However, I think it is mostly if not completely using the first definition because it seems to go better with dedication. It doesn't quite work as that in my opinion (so I can understand your confusion):

*"My inherent qualities of mind and character have become more rooted in this field"* doesn't really make sense but certain synonyms are clearer: "My nature|mentality has become more rooted in this field"

I think it really just means "My thoughts and feelings" (or indeed interests, passions as you suggest) and is a slightly fancy and incorrect way of saying it. That there is the metaphor/pun however might have been the motivation behind using it and it makes it good in my opinion: I'd generally prefer a slightly amusing/confusing sentence to a boring/perfectly clear one (except when I'm in a hurry).

Comment: One more thing if you please. Can you suggest a different word to replace "disposition" in this sentence? Something that is formal and shows commitment? Thanks again!

Comment: @asdhkashd The words you said are good: "passion", "interests". "Focus" perhaps. "Edification" maybe.